# Printing out integer literals occurrences on unix

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I"m trying to use the grep command to print out all occurrences of integer literals in a foo.txt file, but I can't seem to find a way how.

The only thing I can think of for this is using [0-9] as my pattern, but that prints all lines with occurrences of the number rather than just the literals.

EDIT: Say foo.txt contains:

```
string string1 = "Hello world";
cout << string1.at(2) << endl;
cout << string1at(3) << endl;
```

Then the expected output would be:

```
cout << string1.at(2) << endl;
cout << string1at(3) << endl;
```

Comment: And what do you mean by "integer literals" here? Are you trying to get, say, '5820' instead of occurrences of '5', '8', '2', and '0'?

Comment: What I've done is grep [0-9] foo.txt, but that prints out all occurrences.

Comment: By int literals, I mean integers that are coded as the number they represent. For example, if I have i = 2, i =3, 2 and 3 would be literals, but if I have string2 = "hello", the 2 in string 2 would not be a literal since it's being used as a part of string2's name.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. What about: `char a[] = "this is 21 characters";`? Frankly, writing a regex to avoid printing the 21 in there is nigh-on intractable.  If you have to take into account comments too, then…well, suffice to say, rather you than me.  Which version of `grep` do you have available to you?  Does it support ERE's (`-E`)?  Does it support PCRE (usually `-P`).  Which variant of Unix are you working on?  (Note that the `-o` option being mooted is available with GNU `grep` and relatives — BSD/Mac OS X also supports it.)

Comment: I'm just using a basic grep. I don't know anything past that.

Comment: And what is the expected output of the example file in your post?

Comment: cout << string1.at(2) << endl;
cout << string1at(3) << endl;

Comment: Like the output in my answer?  You should edit your post and put the expected output there, so it readable.

Comment: So you like to post the line that contains number between parentheses?

Comment: let's just say they're lines 1,2, and 3 accordingly

Comment: It still unclear what is your pattern to get these lines. What does the two expected lines have that line `1` does not have, since its not printed.

Comment: Oh that's what you meant.
The integer 2 in line1 is not being used as the number 2, but rather as part of a string name, while the numbers in the 2nd and 3rd line are being used as integers.

Comment: line 1 `string string1 = "Hello world"`;` does not contain number with value `2` and what number do you refer to in line 2 and 3? The one in parentheses `(2)` and `(3)`?  Or does this `string1.at(2)` refer to a variable that contains some value?? This is going no where!!!

Answer (score 1):

Some like this:

```
awk -F"[()]" '$2' foo.txt
cout << string1.at(2) << endl;
cout << string1at(3) << endl;
```

Or to make sure it contains numbers between parentheses:

```
awk -F"[()]" '$2~/[0-9]+/' file
cout << string1.at(2) << endl;
cout << string1at(3) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep -o [1-9][0-9]* foo.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using lookaround assertions:

Test string:

```
hello 1234 hello234h 122test 123
```

Regex:

```
grep -o "(?<=\s|^)([0-9]+)(?=\s|$)" foo.txt
```

Matches:

```
"1234", "123"
```

Regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/vP5zD7

Comment: Your `grep` command does not work.  You are using regular expression constructs which are only supported with `grep -P`.  (Easy to fix, if you have that option available.)