# Problems using grep to print integer literals

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I'm trying to use regex to match and print out lines that have integer literals but I can't seem to get it working. I've worked on part of the matching using a regex tutorial and came up with

(-|=)?([0-9])

I try to put this in grep but it doesn't output anything for my file. I'm doing

```
grep "(-|=)?([0-9])" my_fork.c
```

I also looked at a previous stack overflow question([Printing out integer literals occurences on unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21643321/printing-out-integer-literals-occurences-on-unix)) and tried to use his method but it also came out nothing for me so I'm quite a bit confused. Can someone help me get this regex working?

Here's my file for context

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void processPrint(char * argv[], char * test, int i){
    int j = 0;
    for(; j < atoi(argv[1]); j++){
        printf("PID: %d %c\n", getpid(), test[i]);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    exit(0);
}


void mainProcess(char * argv[], pid_t * childArray, int i, pid_t process){
    int j = 0;
    for(; j < atoi(argv[1]); j++){
        printf("PID: %d A\n", getpid());
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    childArray[i] = process;

}


void make_forks(pid_t process, char * argv[], pid_t * childArray, char * test){
    int i = 0, main_ran = 0;
    for(; i < 3; i++){
        if ((process=fork()) == 0){
            processPrint(argv, test, i);
        }
        else{
            if(!main_ran){
                mainProcess(argv, childArray, i, process);
            }
            main_ran = 1;
        }
    }
}

void wait_for_children(pid_t * childArray){
    int incomplete = 0;
    while(1){
        int i = 0;
        for(; i < 3; i++){
            if(childArray[i] > 0 && waitpid(childArray[i], NULL, WNOHANG) != 0 ){
                childArray[i] = 0;
            }
            else{ incomplete = 1; }
        }
        sleep(0);
        if(!incomplete){ break; }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    pid_t * childArray= malloc(12), process;
    char test[5] = "BCD";
    make_forks(process, argv, childArray, test);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `grep -P "(-|=)?[0-9]+"` my_fork.c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your grep command like below. Because basic sed won't support the optional quantifier `?` and capturing groups are represented by `\(...\)`

```
$ echo '-5' | grep '\(-\|=\)*[0-9]' 
-5
$ echo '=5' | grep '\([-=]\)*[0-9]'
=5
```

**OR**

```
$ echo '-5' | grep -E '[-=]?[0-9]' 
-5
$ echo '5' | grep -E '[-=]?[0-9]' 
5
```

Add `+` next to `[0-9]` if you want to match one or more digits.

```
grep -E '[-=]?[0-9]+'
```